# How exactly do I get the following GUI in a Firefox extension?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul, firefox-addon-sdk

I am new to Firefox development and am using the Add-on SDK. I would like to know how to get the following user interface in an extension:

[image: screenshot]

Is this interface a panel? If not, what is it and how do I go about getting this interface in a Firefox addon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn't a panel. Your screenshot shows a [XUL-based](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL) dialog window which is why it looks like a native dialog.

The Add-on SDK uses HTML for its needs however, creating a native-looking dialog is hard there. There is a [fork of the Add-on SDK](http://asqueella.blogspot.de/2010/03/jetpack-sdk-and-xul-extensions.html) with XUL support but it is outdated and very experimental.

The other option would be [building a classic extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Building_an_Extension). It can simply have a XUL file for the dialog (using [`<dialog>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/dialog) as root tag) and call [`window.openDialog()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.openDialog) at some point to show it.

Comment: Okay. I guess then i will have to go only with the limitations of a panel because i feel creating a classic extension is long, cumbersome and very difficult.